# How to correctly import a go model in .proto file

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

I am currently working on moving our rest api based go service to gRPC, using protobuf.
I am using some example from the internet, my service.proto file is like

```
syntax = "proto3";
package v1;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

// Taks we have to do
message ToDo {
    // Unique integer identifier of the todo task
    int64 id = 1;
    // Title of the task
    string title = 2;
    // Detail description of the todo task
    string description = 3;
    // Date and time to remind the todo task
    google.protobuf.Timestamp reminder = 4;
}

// Request data to create new todo task
message CreateRequest{
    // API versioning: it is my best practice to specify version explicitly
    string api = 1;

    // Task entity to add
    ToDo toDo = 2;
}

// Response that contains data for created todo task
message CreateResponse{
    // API versioning: it is my best practice to specify version explicitly
    string api = 1;

    // ID of created task
    int64 id = 2;
}

// Service to manage list of todo tasks
service ToDoService {
    // Create new todo task
    rpc Create(CreateRequest) returns (CreateResponse);
}
```

Now in the given snippet we can see we are defining all the request and response in the same .proto file.

I want to define these in a different go file so that these can be used throughout the project, for ex - i have a model file called CreateRequest.go and somehow i can import that in this .proto file and for the rest of the project i can use that CreateRequest model as well so that i don't have to define the same model twice.

1) Is it possible to do this ?

2) If yes, what is the correct syntax for that ?

I am new to this so if the question looks stupid just have a good laugh and forget.

Comment: It works the other way around. Your source of truth are the `*.proto` files, and you generate your Go files from those.

Comment: You can define a `model.proto` file, import it in your main proto file, and compile `model.proto` file wherever you want in your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

" *a model file called CreateRequest.go and somehow i can import that in this .proto file* " - This is not the way. To use a proto file, 
1) Create your api.proto file and dont forget to add a package something like "package apiv1" in that.
2) Compile your proto to a api.pb.go using protogen-go
3) Create an "apihandler.go" file and "import apivi" in that file. So you are importing the proto-generated package "apivi" into your "apihandler.go" file.

And rather than having separate .proto files for requests and responses, it is good to segregate them based on your api versions or any reasonable components of your project.